# Variance keyword (in, out) name reasoning in generic type parameters C#

Tags: c#, .net

I understand the purpose of the variance in generic parameters and how it functions. But i was wondering why the current choice of the keyword for Covariant parameter '**out**' instead of the opposite '**in**'. Given that Covariance allows interface methods to have more derived return types than that defined by the generic type parameters, why we mark the parameter with '**out**' keyword?
Is this because the parameter type must be the 'outer' boundary of that type? My initial perception was it has something to do with the direction of the allowed substitution rather then the boundaries.

To make it a bit more visual here is an example interface declaration:

```
interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    T GetSomething();    
}
```

QUESTION: Why the keyword '**out**' chosen for Covariance over '**in**' keyword?

Comment: Because covariant types can only be returned from methods, i.e. they are the OUTput of the methods. Same for contravariant types, they are the INput of the methods.

Comment: Yes, INput and OUTput.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă That comment would make a good answer!